# "Could not connect..." with OAuth.io Cordova Plugin Popup

Tags: cordova, oauth, inappbrowser

I set up an app in the Authio dashboard and I can authenticate to facebook and twitter successfully from the developer dashboard.

My Cordova project `config.xml` includes the tag `<access origin="*" />`

My project is Angular-based with `ngSanitize` and I have these urls whitelisted with `$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist()`:

```
        'https://oauth.io/**',
        'https://graph.facebook.com/**',
        'https://api.twitter.com/**'
```

My auth function calls `OAuth.initialize()` with my key and the next line is `OAuth.popup(service)`.

When run on Android, the popup just opens and closes quickly. On an iPhone, I get this error in the console:

`webView:didFailLoadWithError - -1004: Could not connect to the server.`

What am I missing to make the popup work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - needed to change OAuth.io dashboard backend setting to "client side flow"